# CSS increase ALL font on website

Tags: html, css, fonts, fill

Alright i know this is a silly question, but i can't find any solutions for it, i don't know if there is a solution.

But on my website [www.skivecore.com](http://www.skivecore.com), i'm trying to make it responsive for everything from mobile sites, to 4k screens. And right now i'm working on the 4k part, and the text is SO small. And i was wondering, if there is a way to increase ALL font-sizes by say 200%, without redefining every class, every id, just to do so?

Also on the website, when your logged in, i want to have things float next to eachother and fill in empty space which doesn't seem to be happening is there any way to fulfill! this with only css? [image: Space not being filled] All the huge gaps between the posts i would like them to be filled with more posts but even using "float:left;" it's not filling in.

```
@media (min-width: 3900px) {
    body {
        width:100%;
        font-size:200% !important;
    }
    main {
        width:2000px !important;
    }
    #mainbody {
        width:2000px !important;
    }
    #profilebody{
        width:1495px !important;
    }
    html{
        width:100%;
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
    #navgo{
        width:2000px;
    }
    #pic{
        width:2000px !important;
    }
    .colmid{
        width:1628px !important;
        overflow:hidden;
    } 
    .post{
        width: 45% !important;
        float:left;
        margin:10px !important;
    }
    #bigload{
        clear:both;
    }
    #postholder{
        clear:both;
    }
    .colmid:after {
        clear:both;
        content:" ";
        display:block;
    }
    #header{
        height:100px !important;
    }
    #headertools{
        height:100px !important;
    }
    .headertoolbox{
        width:2000px !important;
    }
    .searchbar{
        width: 1000px !important;
        height: 75px !important;
        font-size: 50px !important;
    }
    .searchicon{
        height:61px !important;
    }
    .newlogo{
        height: 91px !important;
    }
    .notiimg, #account div{
        width:80px !important;
        height:80px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume your normal small font size is 12px, you need to increase font size in Em's so the notation you would need is:

```
html{
        width:100%;
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
        font-size:12px;
    }    

body {
            width:100%;
            font-size:4em !important;
    }
```

Just remember to replace the html font size with your base font size that you would use on an average screen.

Comment: That didn't work, is there a way to do it when all the items on the website have different base sizes? Such as timestamps are smaller then post text, and post texts are smaller then bolded names. And nav text is different then all of it?